# Adding a static option to ui-select choices

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

In the code bellow options are added dynamically from a database.

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.people">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="value.id as value in options | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

My question is : How to add an option "all" manually into the dropdown. Is there any way to achive that ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add it to `options` in your component/controller after you get the data back from the server. Manually push it as the first item in the array.

```
options.splice(0,0,{id: -1, name: 'all'});
```

Comment: @NamburiAkhil - what do you mean `not working`? Please debug your script and place a break point on this added line of code. Is it hit? Does the `options` variable change? Can you see the newly added array item? What happens on the screen once you do this? Are you passing the same instance of `options` once this code is executed? Are you sure you are not doing the above splice and then overwriting it with the data from the server?

Comment: It works. I get values from a service, but then add dataOpt.splice(0,0,{id: -1, name: 'TODAS'}); and inside method ask if object.id is -1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one `static` object into the JSON `options` in the controller itself.

Use Array [**unshift()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method to adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the new array.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function () {
    vm = this;
    vm.values = [{
        'key': 22,
        'value': 'Kevin'
    }, {
        'key': 24,
        'value': 'Fiona'
    }];
    vm.values.unshift({'key': '', 'value': 'Static'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.11.2/select.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.11.2/select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <ui-select tagging ng-model="vm.selected" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="val in vm.values | filter: $select.search track by val.value">
            <div ng-bind="val.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
        
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.people" theme="bootstrap">
<ui-select-match>{{ $select.selected }}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="choice in ['option 1', 'option 2']">
    <span>{{ choice }}</span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `options` list as-is, and only add the static option in the dropdown, this will work:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="value.id as value in [ staticOption ].concat(options)">
```